# Android Get User Current Location using LocationListener inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, gps, location

I am currently doing a project where the app will get the user's current location and display it on the textview all happening inside a fragment. I don't get any errors but for some reason it doesnt work..

Here is some part of my code.
All permissions in  the manifest and imports are all good..

Another Strange thing is my app doesnt display anything in my logcat when i click the button.

Note: all codes are inside a fragment

Hope someone can give me a hint or two thanks!

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationListener;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener listener;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View myinflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    final TextView cords = (TextView) myinflate.findViewById(R.id.welcome);
    final Button butt = (Button) myinflate.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);
    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            cords.setText(location.getLatitude() +" "+location.getLongitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, listener);
            }
        }
    });

    return myinflate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens on Android M version or later

This block:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
```

Instructs the Button event handler to do nothing if the application doesn't have the permissions.

The solution is to either request the permissions from the fragment:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(LocationSurface.PERMISSIONS_LOCATION, AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
            }
}else{....}
```

Or, from the emulator, settings -> applications -> your app -> Permissions -> grant the location permission

Comment: Thanks for replying!

Comment: The two variables LocationSurface and AppConstants cannot be resolved?

Comment: LocationSurface & AppConstants are custom variables in my App

    public static final String[] PERMISSIONS_LOCATION = {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    };

    public static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 2;


For more info, please refer to:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html